# How can I prevent Java audio playback from occasionally failing?

Tags: java, audio-player

My application plays a warning sound on invalid input.

This usually works fine, but sometimes it stops working for good (if I stress it a bit) and throws a `LineUnavailableException: unable to obtain a line` and continues to do so every time it tries to play a sound until the application is restarted.

My code looks like this:

```
URL url=MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/app/sound/fail.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
DataLine.Info info=new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
Clip clipFail=(Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clipFail.open(ais);
clipFail.start();
```

I tried reusing the clip, but could not get it to work more than once. Is that even possible?

If I add:

```
finally {
    if (clipFail!=null) {
        clipFail.close();
    }
}
```

it works, but the application becomes unresponsive until the sound has stopped playing.

So do I really need to manually spawn a new `Thread` to play a sound?

I haven't been able to stress that approach enough to fail, so it seems to work fine, but I feel like there should be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: As far as I know you need a separate thread to play audio in the background.

Comment: the clip will start as many times as you start it - other issues are your stupid IDE - your use of Resource etc - your rest of the program - as long as you dont refine it to a single point of question there will be no answers